# Android compare string with two method but still not work

Tags: android

Can you help me, why my code not work?

Output :

03-17 16:54:25.488: D/wew(3821): msg :test

03-17 16:54:25.488: I/System.out(3821): #1: false

03-17 16:54:25.488: I/System.out(3821): #2: false

And this is my code :

```
        charsRead = in.read(buffer);
                        if (charsRead != 1) {
                            String message = new String(buffer).substring(
                                    0, charsRead).toString();
                            Log.d("wew", "msg :" + message);

                            String w1 = "test";
                            String w2 = message;

                            if(w1 == w2){
                                System.out.println("#1: true");
                                } else {
                                System.out.println("#1: false");
                                }

                                if(w1.equals(w2)){
                                System.out.println("#2: true");
                                } else {
                                System.out.println("#2: false");
                                }

                        }
```

Comment: for string comparison you need to use `equals(String v)` method. `==` is used to compare references not values.

Comment: thanks for reply :) . I found my problem. the string have new line.